# Numpy.random.normal gives bad results

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, statistics

I tried to model a random number using `numpy.random.normal`. From this random number (mean=0, std=1)

1. I draw multiple samples of similar size (e.g., m=100)
2. I compute the std of each sample
3. I take the mean of all standard deviations

Theoretical statistics, and also R tells me that this must converge towards the chosen std (which is 1). But somehow, using numpy (and scipy.stats), it does not.

This code generates a figure that shows this strange behavior:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm, tstd

# system setup
m = 100         # number of measurments
sigma = 1       # sensor std

ez = np.arange(1,6,.05)
sample_sizes = [int(10**e) for e in ez]

# testing normal and std - they seem to work fine
sig_est = []
for n in sample_sizes:
    sample = np.random.normal(0, sigma, (n*m))
    sig_est += [np.std(sample)]
plt.plot(ez, sig_est, marker='.', color='b', ls='', label='numpy - no means')

# numpy implementation of problem
sig_est = []
for n in sample_sizes:
    sample = np.random.normal(0, sigma, (n,m))
    sigma_est = np.std(sample, axis=1)
    sig_est += [np.mean(sigma_est)]
plt.plot(ez, sig_est, marker='.', color='k', ls='', label='numpy')

# scipy.stats implementation
sig_est = []
for n in sample_sizes:
    sample = norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=sigma, size=(n,m))
    sigma_est = tstd(sample, axis=1)
    sig_est += [np.mean(sigma_est)]
plt.plot(ez, sig_est, marker='.', color='r', ls='', label='scipy.stats')

plt.gca().set(xlabel = 'Number of samples [log10]')
plt.gca().legend()
plt.gca().grid(color='.9')
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting one, because it's not a random number generator problem but a mathematics one :-) The short answer is that everything is working as expected.

The point is, in the first example you are taking a larger and larger sample of i.i.d. Gaussians and computing their standard deviation using `np.std`. This converges to 1, as your plot shows.

In the second plot, you are computing the standard deviation always over 100 elements, and then averaging these. In this way you are not computing the limit std over many elements, but rather the bias of the estimator of the standard deviation. Which, as you found out, is not zero! This is for two reasons:

- The default numpy implementation of the standard deviation is the square root of the estimator for the variance that minimizes quadratic risk (i.e. 1/n sum of the quadratic errors). This is *not* the unbiased estimator for the variance, which would start by 1/(n-1). You can get the latter by passing the parameter `ddof=1` to `np.std`, see documentation here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html.
- ... but even if you did that, you wouldn't get 0 bias. That's because you're plotting the std, not the variance; i.e. to get exactly 1 you should square the results after computing `np.std` and before taking the mean. You can see that if you replace your line

```
sig_est += [np.mean(sigma_est)]  # equivalent to sig_est.append(np.mean(sigma_est))
```

by

```
sig_est.append(np.mean(np.std(sample, axis=1, ddof=1)**2))
```

in the second block of your code, you'll indeed get convergence to 1.

As to the last implementation using scipy, it seems to use yet another normalization: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.tstd.html

They call it "unbiased" but it's clearly not, on the one hand because your plots clearly show it, on the other hand because the exact factor to get an unbiased estimator (for Gaussians) is much more complicated than n/(n-1), see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation

Comment: *"They call it 'unbiased' but it's clearly not, ..."*  Indeed, that's a mistake in the documentation.